# Static initialize struct to zero

Tags: c, struct, static, initialization

more basic approach:

```
struct TEST
{
    float c;
    unsigned int c1;
    double c2[5];
} t = {0};
```

gives the warning:

> warning: missing initializer for field 'c1' of 'struct TEST' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]

while setting C to int, long, char (but NOT array) etc...

with array it gives warning:

> warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]

was:
I have the following line like this:

```
#define ADD_STRUCT_TO_ARRAY(xu) X(xu, &(struct xu){})SEP
```

which is needed because that structs have to be initialized in many places. But it gives me the warning:

> warning: missing initializer for field 'a1' of 'struct A' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]

by C99 standard it should initialize to zero and get rid of the warning?

changing to

```
#define ADD_STRUCT_TO_ARRAY(xu) X(xu, &(struct xu){0})SEP
```

get ALMOST rid of the warning but NOT IF the first element of the struct is a float or double.

any idea what is going on?, also setting 0.0 seems not helpful

Comment: So what is X and SEP, and what warning are you almost not getting?

Comment: edited with clearer example.X and SEP are macro you can easily ignore.

Comment: Thank you, your edited example is indeed much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` is definitively not a valid initializer in C, thus the first warning that you see. (It is valid for C++, but the construct of "compound literal" which is used here isn't).

Now once you have at least one initializer, this is correct C. If you have a lot of warning flags on, some compilers give you additional diagnostics. In the case that you have here, these are just annoying. `{ 0 }` is *the* default initializers as it is foreseen by the C standard. I'd just switch that particular warning (missing-field-initializers) off, if there is no other easy way to calm it.

Comment: edited the question. So i have to turn off warning, no way around it.

Comment: but still, why the warning if this is safe and standard to use?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to use. The C standard forces all fields that are not mentionned to be initialized to `0`, and it also explicitly foresees that you can leave out levels of `{}` if you like.

Comment: The warning is probably there because it isn't *always* safe to use, thus making its usage partially dangerous. One edge case that has bitten me before is combining it with an array initializer, like struct {...} t[2] = {{0}, {0}} – this does NOT zero-initialize both structs! It could also be there because sometimes you wanted to provide all of the parameters and want to make sure you didn't miss one somewhere.

Comment: @BonzaiThePenguin, I don't see what you are talking about. YES, it zero-initializes both struct. Even  if the target object is an array, initializing only one element *has* to initialize all other elements to `0`. This is so standardized. If your compiler didn't do it, it was not conforming.

Comment: It bit me [here](https://github.com/BonzaiThePenguin/WikiSort/commit/d016c58d50116fddeaa27a1cd2e96b6600710540), but I can't reproduce it on the latest version of clang so it's maybe it was a compiler bug?

Comment: Yes, this must have been a bug. If you can't rely on that, the compiler is completely unusable.